# Issue with open and running already existing Magnolia-CMS project

Tags: magnolia

I started looking at the Magnolia CMS system and found a project on the web and I can't open it and run it.
This are the files:

### `author.tar`

### `magnolia.tar.xz`

### `public.tar.xz`

### `magnolia.tar`

I tried to add the files into apache folder and run it, I tried with Magnolia CLI to run it, but with no success.
I miss something, but I'm completely new to Magnolia, so I have no idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's what is _inside_ these files that is important.  The Tomcat {{webapps}} dir is going to want to see {{.war}} files, for example.  So, assuming {{magnolia.tar}} is extracted, and it contains {{magnolia.war}}, _that_ is what you need to have to run Magnolia.  A good explanation may be found here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Deploying+Magnolia+as+WAR+file.

Answer (score 2):

These pages should be sufficient to get started.

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Getting+started+with+Magnolia

If you fancy CLI, then 
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Magnolia+CLI

Hope that helps,

Cheers,